# (dis)advantages of staging dev->production using 'drush rsync' vs 'git'?

Tags: drush, version-control, staging

I set up a Drupal site under git control for development work.

It's parented in a master, bare GIT repo, and as changes are made in my various project-work git clones, and pushed back to the master, a post-update hook immediately pushes the changes to a single live Staging website (http://staging.loc.). Nothing special, works as expected.

I've also drush-aliased the site "@STAGING". On occassion, I want to promote my changes from the Staging site to a production server.

Two relatively straightforward methods come to mind:

(1) At a point in time when the Staging site appears stable, create the Production site as a git checkout from the master repo,

(2) use `drush rsync` + `drush sql-sync` from the staging site to the production site.

Both can be made to work.  Other than the fact that (2) seems more Drupal-centric/aware by nature -- drush is, after all, a Drupal-specific set of tools -- what are the relative merits of the two approaches?

Is there any particular reason I should consider (1) over (2)?

In either case "Everything" is under at least one instance of revision control ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used both techniques.  Both can be used to guarantee that the same files that you test on @stage end up on @live.  The advantage of rsync is that you do not end up with extra files (e.g. ".git" and associated) on your production server.  I tend to rsync to a vps, and use git on a box I own (e.g. intranet sites).

Comment: Thanks for the point.  I was just looking at the exclusion options.  That helps keep things clean.  Iiuc, I need to specify what to exclude with `"rsync' => array ('exclude-paths' => '.git:.DS_Store:.gitignore:.gitmodules:',"` in the .rc file, though I'm not yet sure if I need that in both the source and target alias' specifcations or just one or the other.

Comment: .git should be ignored by default.  Run 'drush --simulate rsync [options] @a @b' to see the exact rsync command that Drush will run.  Use --include-vcs if you want drush rsync to include .git and other vcs related files.

Comment: I need to read up in more detail; I didn't realize that .git was excluded.  Thanks for the simulate hint too.  Re: the OP, I think I'll stick with the 'drush rsync' as it's designed to be a deploy method for drupal & works.  git can work of course but Ive now come across enough comments that it's notdesigned for deploy ...

Answer (score 1):

The problem with using drush rsync is that if you have multiple people pushing changes to the server.

Your example only shows one person pushing changes.

If you have developer A pushing her changes and then developer B pushing his changes you want git to mop up the conflicts, or make developer B mop up the conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

I actually use both.  svn/git and rsync serve two different purposes. svn/git is for source control, `rsync` and `sql-sync` is for syncing staging and prod efficiently. `drush rsync @staging @prod` is very hard to beat in terms of simplicity, and is dreadfully easy to integrate in most any `continuous Integration` environnment should you want to dive even deeper in code quality  craziness/methodologies.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I use Git for version control, deployment and syncing various server codebases and then rsync to move/sync users files (ignored by adding certain paths to the .gitignore file).